# "The team had comes" versus "the team had come"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

Which among the following sentence is correct?

> The team had **comes** up with a database table design through with the rules and its definitions can be stored.

> The team had **come** up with a database table design through with the rules and its definitions can be stored.

From my perspective, the first sentence is correct as "the team" is singular. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

“Had comes” is ungrammatical. I don't think it's a mistake a native would make, except through inattention (typo). Here, *come* is a past participle, and cannot take any inflection.

The present tense would be “the team comes up”. This is a third-person-singular *-s*, not a plural *-s*: *come* is a verb, not a noun. Only nouns take a plural mark in English.

Occasionally, you will find the [plural used for collective nouns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_differences#Formal_and_notional_agreement) in British English (but rarely if ever in American English). There is no morphological difference with the past perfect as used in this sentence, but there would be a difference if the sentence was cast in the present perfect: “the team has come up” (grammatical or formal agreement of the verb with the subject: the noun *team* is singular) vs. “the team have come up” (notional or semantic agreement of the verb with the subject: a *team* is many people). It don't think a plural verb would ever be used in the present tense: “*<s>the team come up</s>” sounds wrong, though I can't explain why. (Note: I am not a native English speaker.)

There are probably other typos in your sentence. I can't parse it around the middle: should *through with* be *through which*? I don't know what the antecedent of *its* is meant to be: grammatically it could be the team, the database or the design, but none of these make sense. If the antecedent is meant to be *the rules*, the pronoun should be *their*.

Answer (score 1):

We attach 's/es' at the end of the verb if the subject is 3rd person singular. This rule is followed only if the tense is Simple Present.

> He goes to school.

> He eats food.

> They play football.

In this case, it's a present perfect or past perfect tense; only the third form of the verb is used irrespective of singular or plural subject.

> They have gone to the temple. *It is not "They have go the temple."*

> He has cooked today. *It is not "He has cooks today."*

I think your confusion would have arisen from the fact that first and third form of 'come' are same: come, came, and come.

Comment: If the subject is singular **and it's in the third person**. You don't say “I goes to school”, even though the subject is singular and it's in the simple present tense.

Comment: Also, what you call first and third form of _come_ are the bare infinitive and the past participle.